# Vc addon not displaying properly as adde

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

I have made the visual composer addon to meet one of the requirement. However I have found that it always come above the other vc elements.

I have tried to add the class as per vc composer other elements

```
public function sim_product($attr)
{ 
     ?>
<div class="vc_column-inner"><div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
<div class="more-project-list">
     <?php 
            $select =  $attr['sim_product_id'];
             $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'products','post__in' => explode(",",$select) ));
            if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
            <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) 
            { $query->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="single-blk" style='background-color: <?php echo the_field('colour');?>'>
                    <div class="title">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a>
                    </div>
                <figure>
                        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $query->ID ) )
                              { 
                                    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $query->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
                                    <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="">
                        <?php }?>
                </figure>
                <div class="category">
                <?php 
                     $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $query->post->ID, array( 'Product_category') ); 
                     foreach ( $terms as $term ) { echo $term->name;} 
                ?>
                </div>
        </div>

     <?php }}?>   

    </div>
        </div></div></div></div>

<?php

}
```

It isnt coming where I have placed it it always come on top

Comment: I think your question is incomplete. Please check once again : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Kindly let me know what things you need in more details I will add into it.

Comment: " come above the" what is after that ??

Comment: Edited above question